# Playing a mp4 video file using MPMoviePlayerController showing error randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play mp4 video files using MPMoviePlayerController.
 Here is the code I am currently using:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                                      videoLink];
                        MPMoviePlayerController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc  ]init];
                        [controller`enter code here` prepareToPlay];
                        self.mp = controller; //Save obj reference
```

Also I am re using same player object because have to load another video file as soon as next or previous clicked on UI.

```
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, yMargin, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width*9/16); //Set the size

 [self.view addSubview:controller.view];//Show the view
 [controller setContentURL:url];
 [controller play]; //Start playing
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.mp ];
```

Sometimes it's loading video properly but randomly showing an error message as given below.

```
 itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
                    kind = 1;
                    new = 2;
                    old = 0;
                }
If error comes it doesn't load any other video afterwards at least for next 15(approx.) attempts.This behaviour is very random as sometimes it keeps showing the error in log and player doesn't load the video at all.
```

Has someone else faced this similar issue ? I found many questions posted related to this problem but nothing seems to be working for me.

> Other solution i found playing a video using web view but auto play
>   doesn't work for web view.

Comment: I also faced your problem..I over come that by using WebView loading html.(Auto play might work)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please suggest how to enable auto play for web view ?

Comment: My html is different as I am loading only youtube videos. In my html code we are sending you tube video ID to it with autoplay option and it works well..
Ask your .Net team to build html with autoplay by passing URL...!